# How can I automate a release build in hudson?

Tags: build, automation, hudson, release

I have a release job, which I would like to automate. But I've only found the functionality to schedule a normal Build in hudson - and not a release build.

Which possibilities do I have?

Comment: How your release build differs from a normal build?

Comment: What are you using to do your build in Hudson?  Ant?  Maven?  Something else?

Comment: In my releasebuild several ant tasks are proceeded (e.g. pre-build, post-build steps...). Also included is a maven build in order to build the artifacts. So when I trigger the time controlled build only the maven build starts without the ant tasks...Any idea?